# Embedding Gmaps in HTML

Tags: javascript

I am working on embedding Google maps on HTML...

I want a javascript code that works same as creating one we do in Mymaps of Google maps. I want to add the function markers, polyline and polylines on a road..

I tried hard to do the same but did get exactly the look and the polylines doesnot work

I will be very thankful if I get the answer

Comment: I think you need to add some detail and describe what "Mymaps" does exactly

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to research how to interact with the Google Maps API.